# Compact interval $\implies $ boundary is a null space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact interval. How can I prove that the boundary of $I$ is a null space?

The definition for nullspace I want to use is that M is a nullspace, if for $\varepsilon \gt 0 $ there exists a finite number of intervals $I_k$, such that $$M \subset \cup I_k $$ and $$\sum_k V(I_k) \lt \varepsilon$$

It somehow seems intuitive to me, but I can't write down a formal proof...

Comment: "Interval" doesn't really make sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For a general compact *set* this result is false, as can be shown using fat Cantor sets. Something like this might be true for the boundary of an open set, though.

Comment: With interval in $R^n$ I mean $[a_1,b_1] \times ... \times [a_n,b_n] $

Comment: Terminology: You meant "null set". Saying null space instead would be fine, except that "null space" already means something else...

Answer (score 2):

First, prove that the boundary of $I$ is the union of $2n$ intervals $J_k^i$ in $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, or more precisely,
$$J_k^i=[a_1^1,a_1^2]\times\cdots\times[a_{k-1}^1,a_{k-1}^2]\times\{a_k^i\}\times[a_{k+1}^1,a_{k+1}^2]\times\cdots\times[a_n^1,a_n^2]$$

(Superscripts are not powers; they are, well, superscripts).

To finish, substitute $\{a_k^i\}$ by $[a_k^i-\epsilon,a_k^i+\epsilon]$.

Comment: Could you explain your first idea?

Comment: Think about what the boundary of that interval actually _is_.